# Use bash script to setup tmux windows

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to write a script that will setup tmux windows for rails development, so far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-window -n vim
tmux new-window -n guard
tmux new-window -n console/server

tmux select-window -t 3
tmux send-keys -t 3 'rails server' C-z
```

What I want, on that specific window, is to run `rails server` and then send it to the background. The thing is, all I get is `^Z`and the usual prompt after a couple of seconds.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine those tmux commands so that they’re all received by the same session. Separate by `\;` (escaped to get all the way to tmux):

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux new -stest \; \
  new-window -n vim \; \
  new-window -n guard \; \
  new-window -n console/server
  select-window -t 3 \; \
  send-keys -t 3 'rails s &' Enter
```

I don't see the `C-z` working, but you can achieve the same with `&` backgrounding.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: To get those names to stick, the first line above `new-window` needs to be `set-option -g allow-rename off \; \ `.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a session to attach everything to.  For instance:

```
tmux new-session -s c64 -n vim -d
tmux new-window -t c64 -d -n guard
tmux new-window -t c64 -d -n console
tmux send-keys -t c64:console 'rails server &' Enter
tmux select-window -t c64:console
tmux attach -t c64
```

creates a session called `c64` with 3 windows.  It will then send the command to the 3rd window, make it the current window and attach to the session.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make a good use of [IniTmux](https://github.com/iasj/IniTmux). It is a python script I have created.